# Code Reviews on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic, off-topic, scope

There are two related questions here:

**Question 1: Reviewing proof scripts?** I just formalized a type system in Coq (and I'm almost certain it is not "idiomatic Coq"), would it be appropriate to ask for a "code review" of my short script here? I honestly do not know what's considered idiomatic (or "best practices") in Coq, and I'd like to learn them, while correcting my script.

**Question 2: Reviewing implementations of proof assistants?** I've been tinkering around with implementing proof assistants in Standard ML; ostensibly, "down the road", I may desire a code review of some of these toy models. Would this be a proper place for such requests, or should I go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?